# MySQL rejecting date

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL 8
```

My query:

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `start_date` = '2007-04-09' AND `eligibility` = 1 WHERE `user_id` = 36;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2007-04-09'
```

I checked the type for the ***start_date*** field and it it set to ***date***.

When I check the row, I find that it has NOT been modified, even though this is a warning.

I am using the PHPMyAdmin interface to interact with the MySQL DB/Server.

Any ideas?

## ANSWER:

The answer is that I used an AND statement, instead of a comma. I have not used MySQL for a while. I use ORM instead, so I did not notice the error, and the error message threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting start_date to:

```
'2007-04-09' AND `eligibility` = 1
```

You need a comma instead of `AND` there if you want to set eligibility too.

That specific message comes because `'2007-04-09' AND` interprets that string as a Boolean, which it is calling a DOUBLE.